# Performance Testing of RESTFUL Web Services that is doing GET only

Tags: testing, load-testing, performance-testing, stress-testing

We have made a RESTFUL Web services that is doing GET calls to the database currently. 
I am looking for some tools that I can use to test our RESTFUL Web Services by simulating the load that we are going to have in our Production.

I just need to test the RESTFUL web services end to end response time. If we are making around  10000 calls or running it for around more two three minutes.

So what kind of testing we should do for this? And I looked into the JMeter as well but it was very confusing for me to do the testing for GET Calls of RESTFUL Web Services.

What tools we in general should use to test the RESTFUL Web Services

Comment: You would need an integrated test suite that allowed you to define  target profiles of metrics and constraints during load with what if manipulation regarding hardware and latency. The better test would tie into existing code manipulating header/url authentication, if required. Another important piece is the ability to pull real data from a load test repositories to include in your tests' output?  I have used freely available SoapUI|Fiddler for small scripts. On Windows, I use Visual Studio Test Suite 2010 for Load Testing. I don't know if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your web service is java based, JMeter would be a good option.

Comment: Yes its a Java based. Any tutorail that I can follow to do the performance testing of my RESTFUL Web Services? I have taken a look at lot of tutorials but not able to understand properly what they are trying to do and how to see the result meaning what is the average response time and max response time.

Comment: http://jmeter.apache.org/
you can find all the resources you need to use JMeter, tutorial, vedios, doc , pretty straight forward and really easy to pick up.

Comment: What if it is not java based? As REST is purely on resource based, the how could the implementation language/framework impact the performance tool?